Injecting customized DbContext into Asp.NET controller during integration test
I have the following simplified ASP.net API controller to test:
[Route("api")]
public class CustomerController(Func<DataContext> factory) : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("customer")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] CustomerRequest request)
    {
        using var context = factory.Invoke();
        var uow = new UnitOfWork(context);

        await uow.CustomerService.Create(request.ToCustomer());

        return Ok();
    }
}

And below is my test:
[Collection(nameof(ControllerTestCollection))]
public class CustomerApiTest(IntegrationTestFactory factory)
{
   private readonly HttpClient client = factory.CreateClient();

    [Fact]
    public async Task TestCreateCustomer()
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/customer", new CustomerRequest(1, "Customer 1"));

        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
}

And below is my customized WebApplicationFactory:
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureTestServices
    (
        services => 
        {
           services.RemoveDbContext<DataContext>();
           services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseMySql(testcontainer.GetConnectionString()));
           services.EnsureDbCreated<DataContext>();
        }
    );
}

When I run the test, the controller keeps using the real DB setting instead of the one I setup for this test, so basically it ignores the DataContext pointing to DB hosted by Testcontainers. But I can assure that the customized WebApplicationFactory passed to the test correctly points to test DB.
I'm new to this ASP.Net & EF Core so any help would be greatly appreciated.

looking for this package Xunit.DependencyInjection ?

Please explain the problem I'm facing and how the package solves it.

Library will call Startup.ConfigureServices(...) and configure services automatically when running tests. Then you can inject into Test's constructor configured services.

WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> is used to create a TestServer for the integration tests. TEntryPoint is the entry point class of the SUT, usually Program.cs.
**You are injecting deletgate Func<DataContext> in controller's constructor. DI container has to know how to construct Func so we need to add it explicitly
builder.Services.AddTransient<Func<DataContext>>(cont => () => cont.GetService<DataContext>()!);
**
Runs fine, passes DataContext correctly
Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var builder = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder
    .Services
    .AddControllers(options => options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false)
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();


builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestApp"));

builder.Services.AddTransient<Func<DataContext>>(cont => () => cont.GetService<DataContext>()!);

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services
        .AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
    );

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();

app.Run();

public partial class Program { }

CustomWebApplicationFactory
using System.Data.Common;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> where TProgram : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var dbContextDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<DataContext>));
            services.Remove(dbContextDescriptor!);

            var dbConnectionDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbConnection));
            services.Remove(dbConnectionDescriptor!);

            // Create open SqliteConnection so EF won't automatically close it.
            services.AddSingleton<DbConnection>(container =>
            {
                var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
                connection.Open();

                return connection;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>((container, options) =>
            {
                var connection = container.GetRequiredService<DbConnection>();
                options.UseSqlite(connection);
            });

 services.AddTransient<Func<DataContext>>(cont => () => cont.GetService<DataContext>()!);

        });

        builder.UseEnvironment("Development");
    }
} 

Test
public class CustomerApiTest(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory) : **IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>>**
{
    private readonly HttpClient client = factory.CreateClient();

    [Fact]
    public async Task TestCreateCustomer()
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync("/WeatherForecast");
    }
}

DB Context
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : DbContext(options)
{
    public virtual DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }

}

Controller
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, Func<DataContext> factory) : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries =
        [
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        ];

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger = logger;
        private readonly DataContext context = factory.Invoke();

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var messages = context.Messages.ToList();

            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}




Microsoft Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-8.0#customize-webapplicationfactory
class-fixture: https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#class-fixture

Hi If you look at my Controller, it's injected Function of DataContext insted of DataContext itself, can you try the same?

could you please share how you are registering delegate for dbcontext in your program.cs?

I've updated the code and answer above, seems to be passing delegate of dbcontext correctly

Hi. Thanks for your help. After adding services.AddTransient<Func>(cont => () => cont.GetService()!); to CustomWebApplicationFactory it works as expected.

could you please mark it as solved
